# Common associative table for multiple many-to-many

Tags: database, jpa, java-ee-8

How do I create a common associative table for multiple many-to-many? Why does it not work?

```java
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="CARS",
        joinColumns=
        @JoinColumn(name="RANGE_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns=
        @JoinColumn(name="MODEL_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
)
private List<Models> models;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="CARS",
        joinColumns=
        @JoinColumn(name="RANGE_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns=
        @JoinColumn(name="TYPE_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
)
private List<Types> types;
```

I want to have associative table "CARS":

```
range_id | model_id | type_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just image what would happen if you'd add a new type to the list of types or a new model to the list of models. How would the new row look like? Model and Type wouldn't belong together - what they should according to your table definition.

What you are looking for is an `Embeddable`:

```
@Embeddable
public class ModelAndType {
  @ManyToOne
  private Model model;

  @ManyToOne
  private Type type;
}
```

This one can be used in your model:

```
@Embedded
@ElementCollection
private List<ModelAndType> modelAndTypes;
```